# Past perfect or past simple in this case

Tags: grammar

When I  called for  the record ,he first answered me, he did not have it. However he knew the record because it **was true** that the band **had  planned** that they would leave a record in the shop after the gig.In fact he did not know if they had done  it.Then he took my number and said he was going to look for it once we had hung up the phone.After thirty minutes I  received a  phone call: the record was on hold for me.

Would it be possible to change for "it **had been** true that the band  **planned** "because the statement was made first.If this change is possible, is it  necessary to have another past perfect for **planned**, I don't think so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That change hides more of the meaning. "Was" is already in the timeframe of the person answering the phone, so "had planned" pushes it back another step to have already finished by the time the person answered the phone. Those verbs are best left in their current forms.